# How can I load and compress a table at the same time?

Tags: sql-server

I need to load and create a new table from another table by using linked server and compress it while loading it at the same time.

I use this to load and create the new table :

`select * into [DB].[dbo].[NewTable] from [LinkedServer].[DB].[dbo].[ExistingTable]`

I need to make compression while the loading is running at the same time

Thank you upfront for your Help

Comment: Compression is done on the table, not as part of the `INSERT`. You can't have *some* rows compressed and others not. If you want the table to be compressed, have a read of [Enable Compression on a Table or Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/enable-compression-on-a-table-or-index?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for your explanation. I actually had a look at this page before asking my question. 
Let's suppose that I don't have access to the server that I linked, so each time I need to create a new table from an existing one without having this table's definition. In order to load and compress rows while the load is running. I was looking for a solution, if it was there one, to create, load and compress the final table at the same time but not at the end of the load or in the definition script of the table.

Comment: *"Let's suppose that I don't have access to the server that I linked"* Then how are you getting the data from it..? Magic? For the above statement to work you, by definition, have access to the other host. But the remote host has nothing to do with the compression on the "local" host.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for your explanations.
What I want to say by "Let's suppose that I don't have access to the server that I linked" is that no matter how is the definition of the table in the other host, each time I need to drop, create and load a new table in "local" host. That's why I use `select * into`  instead of `insert` statement.

Comment: So what is your question here then..? How do use `ALTER TABLE` to enable compression? Did you read the linked documentation? There a bit called "[To enable compression on a table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/enable-compression-on-a-table-or-index?view=sql-server-ver15#to-enable-compression-on-a-table)" that I suggest reading. What about that didn't you understand? When you attempted to implement the solution, why didn't it work?

Comment: My question is : Is there a SQL statement that can create, load and compress data in a new table while loading it from an existing one ? I guess that `ALTER TABLE MyTable REBUILD PARTITION = ALL  
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW);` should be done at the end not while the load is running. If this is not possible as you explained "You can't have some rows compressed and others not". How can I add `DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE` to the definition script of the new table please ? In order to get a compressed table at the end, to avoid saturating disk space while the load is running but not after.

Comment: When you `CREATE` the table you can enable `DATA_COMPRESSION` at that point too, @MedEc . See [CREATA TABLE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: @Larnu I got it. Thanks a lot for your precious explanations and help